# VSCode: Keybindings for Tasks by Name or Index

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that I can bind key combinations to the build or test tasks in VSCode. Is it possible to bind to other tasks in my tasks.json by either index or task name?

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't believe this is possible.

The build and test tasks are given special treatment by the application.